# After how many milliseconds can I be sure the file was written in Xul?

Tags: javascript, file-io, xul

I need to write about 50 characters to a file.

I'm calling `nsIConverterOutputStream.writeString()`. So, how many milliseconds after I call it can I start to believe it was written?

Comment: You really *really* shouldn't be doing synchronous disk I/O.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2f%2fO#Writing_to_a_file for how to write to a file in a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to betray a fundamental misunderstanding. The `writeString` method is *synchronous/blocking*. It's done when it's done.

If it *were* asynchronous, there'd still be no sufficient amount of time you could wait to be sure that the write had completed. You could wait until our sun burns out and still not be sure. An asynchronous library would need to provide some method (e.g. a callback) of notifying you when the write is done.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla/html/interfacensIUnicharOutputStream.html#a4fdad6194ea576d502ecc8578876bba0) writeString() will return true on success - so if it returns true, the file had already been written.

Comment: this is for the `nsIUnicharOutputStream`, the [nsIConverterOutputStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIConverterOutputStream) have nothing on it's doc..

Comment: @Tom Brito That's not technically correct, though. The nsIConverterOutputStream has one vital piece of information in its documentation - it inherits from nsIUnicharOutputStream. Likely safe to assume that it's not implementing writeString() for itself.

Comment: Yeah, like @Anthony Grist says, nsIConverterOutputStream inherits from nsIUnicharOutputStream

Comment: cool, but as nsIConverterOutputStream is an interface, I think I'm not able no know which's is the implementation in use..